# Twitter Web Login

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, oauth, http-headers

I am looking at a workflow to try and automate Twitter authentication for applications with a specific user. In order to achieve this (it seems to me: I am a beginning with OAuth workflows) I have to create a session logged in to Twitter through the web.

The application-only workflow is relatively easy to establish with the following code:

```
consumer_key = API_key = "app API key"
consumer_secret = API_secret = "app API secret"
encoded_secrets = base64.b64encode(consumer_key+":"+consumer_secret) # key & secret should be URL-encoded
r =  requests.post("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
               headers={"authorization": "Basic "+encoded_secrets },
               data={"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
```

This retrieves the bearer token that can be used to authenticate an application to Twitter without any user interaction. For example,

```
access_data = json.loads(r.content)
bearer_auth_header = {"authorization": "Bearer "+access_data['access_token']}
timeline_endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json"
response = requests.get(timeline_endpoint,
                              headers=bearer_auth_header)
```

This code works fine (and fails due to authentication failure when the headers are omitted).

When it comes to authorizing an application with a user's identity, however, things are more complex as an account identity has to be authenticated. The standard workflow is to bring up a link in the user's web browser that allows them to authorize the application to access their details through the web (by clicking on a button and submitting a form.

The issue comes when trying to automate this login using a request from a program rather than a web browser. My current attempt looks like this.

```
# access the Twitter login page to receive a '_twitter_sess' session cookie.
twit_response = requests.get("https://twitter.com/login")
# Submit sign-on form through the web
TW_ID = "username"
TW_PW = "password"
login_data = {
              "session[username_or_email]": TW_ID,
              "session[password]": TW_PW,
              "return_to_ssl": True,
              "scribe_log": "",
              "redirect_after_login": "http://holdenweb.com/contact",
              "force_login": True
}
login_response = requests.post("https://twitter.com/sessions",
                               data=login_data, 
                               cookies=twit_response.cookies,
                               headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 "
                                        "(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) "
                                        "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"})
```

This fails (though because this is not web authentication it receives a 200 response). I also observe that despite the `cookies=twit_response.cookies` argument to `requests.post()` the request did not seem to include the session cookie and the User-Agent header is still incorrect. However, I am unsure whether this is the cause of the failure, so I only mention this in case it's relevant.

```
trrh = twit_response.request.headers
for header in trrh:
    print "%s: %s" % (header, trrh[header])
```

prints

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.2 Darwin/12.5.0
```

Can anyone help me make progress, please, it's getting to the stage where I feel I am overlooking some fundamental and possibly quite simple mistake(s).

Comment: The assiduous reader will note that this received a total blanking from the Stackoverflow community. She might care to ask herself why. Some questions shouldn't be answered in public. I won't be posting a bounty ;-)

Comment: This might be a long shot, but (this not being answerable in public and all, as well as being 3 years old) but did you find a means of doing this?

Comment: No. I found other ways to move forward. If I had I wouldn't be publishing the result in any case.

Comment: That's fair. I have another way as well, but it's a bit roundabout. Thank you for getting back to me.